# Serializing and decoding JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I was converting JSON from data when I received an error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'

The data was printed as expected, but the JSON wasn't. I think the code failed in the first line after the `do` statement.

```
do {
    var str: String = "http://localhost:5000/requirements/\(Array.joined(separator: "_"))"
    let url = URL(string: str)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        print(data)
        do {
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data)
            print(json)
            if let json = json {
                print(json)
                let decodedList = try? JSONDecoder().decode(List.self, from: json)
                print(decodedList)
                if let items = decodedList {
                    listToDisplay = items.itemsAsString.components(separatedBy: ",")
                    print(listToDisplay)
                }
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()

    return listToDisplay
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. Why don't you pass the data straight to the JSONDecoder? `JSONDecoder().decode(List.self, from: data)`

Comment: btw you can't  just return the listToDisplay after start downloading.

Comment: Remove your misuse (and unnecessary use) of `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: just do decode immediately

Comment: Ok it works now, thanks everyone.